# how to delete a row from seuqlize table after time

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database, npm

I am working on an app using NodeJS
and i am using sequelize too
i created a table called users and in the users table there is a column stands for active or not lets say i want to delete users who didn't activate their accounts and who have created their accounts 1 hour ago
how do i do that

Comment: I want it to be completely automatic i know i can do 
DELETE statment in mysql

Comment: I think you should consider a CRON Job, or a [MySQL Scheduled Event](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/).

Comment: it's better to write a CRON Job or using a https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule and if you don't want and your project is a hobby project you can do it with ```setInterval()```